# Google Oauth 2.0 Token Request

Tags: delphi, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to connect to Google Calendar Api using oauth. Did I form wrong request or my refresh token has expired?

```
URLString := 'client_id=' + FClientID;
URLString := URLString + '&client_secret=' + FClientSecret;
URLString := URLString + '&refresh_token=' + FRefreshToken;
URLString := URLString + '&grant_type=refresh_token';
Req := TStringStream.Create(URLString);
Resp := TStringStream.Create('');
FHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
FHTTP.DoRequest('POST', 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', Req, Resp, []);

  { Response was:
    ======================
    Recv 31.12.2017. 14:12:59: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
    1f
    {
      "error" : "invalid_grant"
    }
 }
```

Later on I sucessfully manage to get user consent. Thing is - I do not want to ask for user consent EVERY time. Maybe user is over 50 refresh tokens limit? I tried to create new Api in Google Console, bet that did not help.

Succesful code, if no refresh token present is below:

```
if Assigned(FOnAuthorizationContinueQuery) then
      FOnAuthorizationContinueQuery(Self, OkResult, InputResult)
    else
      OkResult := InputQuery(Application.Title, 'Enter your code here:', InputResult);
    if OkResult then
      FCode := InputResult  { that code I copy/pasted from browser }
    else
      Exit;

URLString := 'client_id=' + FClientID;
URLString := URLString + '&client_secret=' + FClientSecret;
URLString := URLString + '&code=' + FCode;
URLString := URLString + '&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob';
URLString := URLString + '&grant_type=authorization_code';
Req := TStringStream.Create(URLString);
Resp := TStringStream.Create('');
try
  try
    FHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    FHTTP.DoRequest('POST', 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', Req, Resp, []);

    { Response was:
      ======================
      Recv 31.12.2017. 14:13:09: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
      X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
      Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="json.txt"; filename*=UTF-8''json.txt
      111
      {
        "access_token" : "token value was here",
        "expires_in" : 3600,
        "refresh_token" : "1/XI11nmVZdOuB1IfBVMEovNffKTKTGgJ5wsId1EwQE9U",
        "token_type" : "Bearer"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to use `EncodeURLElement()` on all the parameters (especially the refresh_token). Like `URLString := URLString + '&refresh_token=' + EncodeURLElement(FRefreshToken);`

Comment: I do not have such function in Lazarus (which is free alternative to Delphi). 

If that helps - when I get access token after authorization with user consent refresh token always changes, and next time it does not work. Also- there was time period when this code was working as intended and did not ask any user consent, but now it does ask every time. 

Is there a way to test if I am out of 50 free refresh tokens?

Comment: You won't easily get out of your 50 free refresh tokens because if you create another the oldest ones get invalid. So this shouldn't be a problem (unless you need ALL those refresh tokens). Look at my Google oauth2 in https://github.com/rvk01/google-oauth2. It's also for Lazarus but I use Synapse for communications which has a EncodeURLElement. But you can create one yourself too. It's just replacing the special characters with %xx (where xx is the hex representation of the characternumber).

Comment: After getting the authenticationcode you retrieve the refresh-token and the first access-token. The access-token is valid for just 6 minutes after which you need to get a new access-token with the refresh-token you got. The refresh-token won't expire (until you reach the 50 max limit in which case the oldest get invalid). So just save the refresh-token (like I did in my code) and use it again and again. But you need to encode the tokens correctly because they do contain special characters (like / or ! etc).

Comment: Sorry, 6 minutes should be 60 minutes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helped me to understand how refresh and access tokens work. I found functions for URL encoding in Indy, applied them and found out that my saved refresh token had extra whitespace.